# When a spring is held from one end and some mass is put on the other end and it's rotated then why does it get stretched?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames, free-body-diagram, spring

While going through a question I found that if we hold a spring from one end and rotate it then it gets stretched. One explanation may be that centrifugal force is acting on it...but if I want to analyse it, taking ground as reference frame then What can be the explanation of it getting stretched. I mean what force is acting on it?

Comment: It would be the centripetal force, but yes that would be the only candidate wouldn't it? If you use the search function you'll find that these kinds of things have often [already been discussed here.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/332734/71413) It seems the spring will not only stretch, but start some kind of complex vibrational motion, depending on the starting conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you are watching a mass move in the ground frame and that mass is not attached to a spring. Then the mass is going to move in a straight line at constant speed in accordance with Newton's first law.

To make the mass move in a curve you have to apply a force to it to deflect it away from the straight line, and that force has to be exerted by the spring because the spring is the only thing interacting with the mass. That means the spring has to be extended because it only exerts a force when it is extended.

This applies to any shape of curve, including the complicated trajectories described in [Motion of a mass attached to a rotating spring](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/332115/motion-of-a-mass-attached-to-a-rotating-spring). Circular motion is a special case because here the force that you need to apply to the mass to deflect it is constant and is always normal to the velocity vector.